# Pandas filtering on multiple columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime, isin

I am trying to filter a dataframe based on a certain date and country name. I have extracted the columns I want the final dataframe to contain. I have also created a list of the country names that I want to filter on.

```
cols_to_keep = projects[['regionname', 'countryname', 'lendinginstr', 'totalamt', 'boardapprovaldate','location', 'GeoLocID', 'GeoLocName','Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Country', 'project_name']]
countries = ['Bosnia', 'Herzegovina', 'Croatia', 'Kosovo', 'Macedonia', 'Serbia', 'Slovenia']
```

Then I try to filter on the date that I want which is April 27th 1992.

```
projects['boardapprovaldate'] < pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(1992,4,27))
```

Then I try applying the date filter on the country names that I want by doing:

```
cols_to_keep[(cols_to_keep['boardapprovaldate'] < pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(1992,4,27))) & 
             (cols_to_keep['countryname'].isin(countries))].sort_values('boardapprovaldate')
```

which only shows me 2 rows when I should have 12 rows

[image]

However, if I try

> str.contains() instead of isin()

method I can retrieve the correct results I want.

```
projects[(projects['boardapprovaldate'] < pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(1992,4,27))) & 
         ((projects['countryname'].str.contains('Bosnia')) | 
         (projects['countryname'].str.contains('Croatia')) | 
         (projects['countryname'].str.contains('Kosovo')) | 
         (projects['countryname'].str.contains('Macedonia')) | 
         (projects['countryname'].str.contains('Montenegro')) | 
         (projects['countryname'].str.contains('Serbia')) | 
         (projects['countryname'].str.contains('Slovenia')))][
    ['regionname', 
     'countryname', 
     'lendinginstr', 
     'totalamt', 
     'boardapprovaldate',
     'location', 
     'GeoLocID', 
     'GeoLocName',
     'Latitude', 
     'Longitude', 
     'Country', 
     'project_name']].sort_values('boardapprovaldate')
```

[image]

Can someone please explain the difference and why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `isin` checks for equality. So values like "Bosnia and Herzegovina" which are not in your `countries` list will not match.

Using `contains` checks for sub-strings. "Bosnia" is a sub-string of "Bosnia and Herzegovina".

###### Example:

```
srs = pd.Series(["Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bosnia"])
>>> srs.isin(["Bosnia"])
0    False
1    True
dtype: bool

>>> srs.str.contains("Bosnia")
0     True
1     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: That makes much more sense. Thanks!